# Setting up gitlab phpstan pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, pipeline

I have tried to start using phpstan pipeline on gitlab according to [this guide](https://www.tremplin-numerique.org/en/how-to-create-a-gitlab-ci-pipeline-to-statically-analyze-php-projects).

The problem is that the pipeline does not work at all (Command 'sh' is not defined) and i don't know how to fix it.

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - check

phpstan:
  stage: check
  image: ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan
  script:
    - analyse --no-progress --error-format gitlab > phpstan.json
```

And here is the pipeline output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.2.0~beta.17.g34ae4a68 (34ae4a68)
  on blue-5.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default -AzERasQ
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
Using Docker executor with image ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan ...
Pulling docker image ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan ...
Using docker image sha256:797d91431d4ecb9c7c570d793db215dec2ae01f942b85e4e6e7cf4e07d07c8f2 for     ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan with digest     ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan@sha256:ac693ee977b314976226205631cd9071364f6c84b3b113f0c9404f9d4747a0b5     ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner--azerasq-project-37231833-concurrent-0 via runner-azerasq-shared-1658326011-    484bb33b...
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/balikobot/BalikobotAdmin/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out e4512b17 as feature/ci-pipeline...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:797d91431d4ecb9c7c570d793db215dec2ae01f942b85e4e6e7cf4e07d07c8f2 for     ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan with digest     ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan@sha256:ac693ee977b314976226205631cd9071364f6c84b3b113f0c9404f9d4747a0b5     ...
                            
  Command "sh" is not defined.  
                            
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that an official Docker image of phpstan uses ENTRYPOINT ["phpstan"] and the Gitlab runner call the image with "sh -c" command. You can override the default entry point (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image):

```
phpstan:
  stage: check
  image: 
    name: ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - phpstan analyse
```

I recommend to use a Docker image for phpstan with concrete version (don't use latest tag).

Comment: It is important to keep the original arguments to phpstan: `phpstan analyse --no-progress --error-format gitlab > phpstan.json`.